# how would i move a folder or the contents from one place to another Via code in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filesystems

Im trying to make a mac app that copies and pastes a folder to another location but i can find a tutorial on how i go along and make an app for the mac what its per pose is A app that makes it easy to move mod files to a games file system. Yes i know theres lots of apps that goes the same but i want to make my own. The structure is theres six NSTextFields three for the mods folders and three for the games folder system like (Mod's Parts Path, Mod's Plugin Path, Mod's Plugin Data Path, Game's Parts Path, Game's Plugin Path and Games's Plugin Data Path). Ive looked on stackflow and Google and couldn't find on tutorial on how to do this maybe im looking in the wrong places. The game that its manly for is for KSP (Kerbal Space Program)

Answer (score 0):

What did you googled? You will need a simple gui application with 6 Labels, 6 TextFields and one Button. There will be one function linked with that button. That function will use data from TextFields and [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s copyItemAtPath:toPath:error: method.
Google something like "osx first app" or "xcode TextField tutorial" for the details on how to create an app with TextField and Button.